# Question about i-adjective without 「い」followed by 「の」

Tags: i-adjectives

> **妖し**の怪談編

I found that 「妖しい」is an i-adjective but in this case the alphabet 「い」is missing. For my understanding, the way to change i-adjective is to replace the last 「い」with「さ」. Or is this a way to change adjective into noun form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is actually しい-adjectives rather than いｰadjectives that we should be looking at here.  しい-adjectives are adjectives that end in 「しい」, and not just 「い」.

Examples: [愛]{いと}しい (beloved)、[懐]{なつ}かしい (dear old)、[麗]{うるわ}しい (graceful)、[妖]{あや}しい (mysterious), etc.

**「[しい-Adjective] minus い plus の」 (Drop the い and add a の)**

makes a kind of ***elegant word*** out of the しい-adjective that also functions adjectivally.

I have no idea at what stage in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language this is taught, but this format is ***quite*** common in Japanese.

Examples: 「懐かしの[歌声]{うたごえ}」 (dear old singing voice)、「愛しのエリー」 (Ellie my love) ← popular song title、「麗しの[君]{きみ}」 (the graceful you), etc.

「妖しの[怪談編]{かいだんへん}」, thus, means "the Mysterious Ghost Stories Edition".

As far as pure meaning, 「妖**しの**怪談編」 and 「妖**しい**怪談編」 are pretty much the same.  ***It is just that the former looks and sounds more elegant and/or refined and kind of more literary*** than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this 「妖し」 form is an old form of 「妖しい」, as seen [here](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%82%84%E3%81%97).

Also, besides the provided book title, I could find just two examples of the colocation, being 「妖しのセレス」 (the anime) and [「怪し火」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/6864/meaning/m0u/%E5%A6%96%E3%81%97).